# How can I prevent tooltip to appears when I hover another element?

Tags: highcharts

I'm developing a chart that have 2 splines and 2 scatter. I use the default tooltip formatter to exhib a tooltip based in the spline data. But when I hover a scatter despite I hide the default tooltip, before show the scatter one, it appears to have triggered again.

How can I prevent the default tooltip to be triggered?

ps: im using Highcharts 3.0.1

EDITED: I tried "chartObj.tooltip.enabled = false" but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this code:

```
chartObj.tooltip.options.enabled = false;
```

Setting to "false" when I hover and to "true" on mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show the tooltip for a particular serie in the chart, see if setting

```
enableMouseTracking: false
```

on you desired serie's properties does it.

Hope this help.

Comment: There's too much series, I must disable it in all series of current chart